# how to call a lesson that a TEACHER has carried out

Tags: word-request

how to call a lesson that a TEACHER has carried out?

I need a short, precise expression which will be used a lot in the documentation of a system that I am writing.

I thought about "delivered lesson", "implemented lesson"?
Would these expressions work? Can you come up with something better?

Examples:

*"The modification history of the ..... lessons."*

*"This view allows you to display .... and planned lessons."*

*"This PHP class is responsible for retrieving data of .... lessons from the database "*

Please help :)

Comment: completed/ covered/ taught maybe? I'm not sure what is it that you want.

Comment: +1 @VarunKN 'covered' is what I'd prefer. Because 'taught' also asks for the activeness of a learner! *covered* is one-sided! Job done (by the teacher!)

Comment: @VarunKN *Completed* is probably the most appropriate of those three.

Answer (score 2):

So, I did a bit of research on Google Ngrams and thought I'll share the details. 
From my comment, I got a couple of suggestions that perfectly fits the context. 
The words I suggested were:

> - Completed.
> - Covered.
> - Taught. (Not the best option)

I searched for the occurrences of *'Completed lessons'*, *'Covered lessons'* and *'Instructed lessons'*. The result showed no occurrences for *'covered'* lessons and *'instructed'* lessons. 
[Google Ngram for *'Covered lessons'*, *'Completed lessons'* and *'Instructed lessons'*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=covered%20lessons%2C%20completed%20lessons%2C%20instructed%20lessons&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompleted%20lessons%3B%2Cc0).
I further dug a bit deeper and checked for occurrences of *'Lessons completed'*, *'Lessons covered'* and *'Lessons instructed'*:
[Google Ngram for  *'Lessons completed'*, *'Lessons covered'* and *'Lessons instructed'*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lessons%20covered%2Clessons%20completed%2Clessons%20instructed&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clessons%20covered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clessons%20completed%3B%2Cc0).
Lessons are generally completed or covered or plainly finished (very informal).

I'll substitute one of your sample sentences with the best possible words you could use, and let you choose the best option, based on your context.

> *"This PHP class is responsible for retrieving data of the **completed** lessons from the database."*

or

> *"This PHP class is responsible for retrieving data of the **covered** lessons from the database."*

**Note**: For this particular sentence, I would recommend **completed**, as it sounds a bit better. But you should try both in your context and choose the best one.

Answer (score 1):

We would use the term "delivered lesson" when opposed to "planned lessons".

I'm coming at this from the angle of an E-Learning developer who works at a university.

Because we have both tradition tutor-led (T) lessons as well as self-taught (S) lessons, we have terminology that applies to one method, the other, or both.

- **Planned Lessons**: These may have been made but students haven't seen them yet. (T/S)
- **Delivered Lessons**: These have been given to students. (T/S)
- **Taught Lessons**: These have a teacher leading the lesson (not necessarily past tense!). (T)
- **Completed Lessons**: The student has reached the end of this lesson. (S)

"**Delivered**" is the most generic term we use to describe lessons that have been presented to students.

Comment: One other option that might work is "past," as in "past lessons," but that could be construed to mean a lesson from a previous course offering that has since been updated. I think "completed" is the best word to use.

Answer (score 0):

Lessons that are taught **by a teacher** are called

> **instructed lessons**
>   **instructed learning**

Lessons which are studied **by a student**, on their own, are called

> **self-study lessons**
>   **self-taught lessons**
>   **self-taught learning**

Generically, **lesson learning** is understood to be taught by a teacher

**Instructed lessons** can take the form of

> **classwork**
>   **lectures**
>   **coaching**

Sometimes **homework assignments** are given to students to be handed in the next day.

Comment: Never ever heard of 'instructed lessons'. Maybe, it's not called *that way* in India!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I mean a lesson that has been done and finished. First, it was a planned lesson, that the Teacher carried it out, so now this is a ... lesson.?

Comment: **Covered** lesson, but **covered** lesson can also apply to **self-study** since there is no context of who did the instruction, only that the material was **covered**. Usually, "the lesson **covered by the teacher**", "the lesson **taught by the teacher**", "what the **teacher taught** today" is used.  Since you are writing a **manual** you could use your own acronym, ie **TL** for **taught lesson**, and just use the acronym in your documentation with an explanation for **TL** in the front

Comment: @MaulikV We don't say 'instructed lessons' outside India, either: http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=44721376

Comment: **Instructed lessons** maybe it's more a UK thing, I think you all know what it means though, strange not used in India